# How can I disable the sound effect that is played when messages pop up from the notification tray?

Tags: windows-10, notifications, system-sounds

Sometimes I want to work on my PC silently without any disturbance. Whenever the notifications pop up from the notification area, a loud chime goes off which distracts me.  The sound also creates extra noise while I am watching videos or listening to music.

It's getting very annoying - How do I disable the sound effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## **How to disable sound for notifications using Control Panel**

While you can disable sounds for individual apps using the Settings feature in Windows 10,  you can also use Control Panel to turn off sound for all notifications. I assume you want all notifications to be muted so here are the steps to take:

- Open Control Panel.
- Click on Hardware and sound.
- Click the Change system sounds link
  [image]
- Under "Windows," scroll and select Notifications
- On the "Sounds," drop-down menu, select (None).
  [image]
- Click Apply
- Click OK

Once you completed the steps, you'll continue to get toast notifications and Action Center will work as before, but you'll not get annoyed with the same sound over and over again every time a new notification arrives.

If you are interested in preventing sound notifications for specific applications please see the [SOURCE](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-turn-sound-notifications-windows-10) of this answer.